# How to see errors from an ionic app from my device

Tags: android, linux, ionic-framework

Fellows I have made an app by using ionic framework.

When I run

```
ionic serve
```

On the terminal it runs as it should be. But when I run it via:

```
ionic run
```

I see on the device the app running by displaying the ionic's loading screen, but after that it does not run as it should be.

What I am asking is how can I see - debug any sort of error from the app running on the device in order to figure out what's wrong?

I am using an Adroid device for the tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by running:

```
adb logcat | grep 'Web Console'
```

On a linux terminal / git bash

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
ionic run android -c -l
```

// -c for consolelogs and -l for livereload

Answer (score 2):

After `ionic run android` command keep fixed to your cable and laptop.

Go to your chrome and type `chrome://inspect` you can see your app in that and click inspect so that you can able to look what is going on in your mobile app and you can debug it.

Comment: This is very useful as logcat often doesn't display the error stack. For me on ionic 4 the command was ionic cordova run android and you must already have an emulator run that has USB debugging turned on!

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional flags when using  `ionic run`.

- -c will show console logs.
- -s will show server logs.
- -l will perform live reload of the application when code changes.

So you can use something like
`ionic run android -cls`

Note that for livereload to work if the device is not connected directly make sure its in the same network as the serving device. Make sure to serve to a local IP address in this case (you can use `ionic address` to change that).